# Cannot use a Django's foreign key result in the template

Tags: python, django

I have two tables in Django models.py connected by Foreign Key.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    src = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)



class Videos(models.Model):
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    content = models.URLField(max_length=1024)
```

In a views.py I write the following code to use it in template

```
def videos(request):
    
    videos = Videos.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
         'videos' : videos,
         'categories' : categories,
    }

        return render(request, 'videos/index.html', context)
```

In the template I use the following jinja tags to output each category name followed by connected posts's titles.

```
{% for category in categories %}
                    
     <li class="nav-item mt-2">
          <a class="nav-link ml-3 pl-0 pb-3 side-menu-section-name" href="#">
               <img src="{{ category.src }}" width="45px" class="pr-2" alt="Video's Category's Icon">By {{ category.name }}
          </a>
     </li>

     {% for video in videos %}
                        
          {% if video.category_id != None %}
                            
              {% if video.category_id ==  category.name %}
                    <!-- Here should be posts titles which are in current category -->
                                
                    {{  video.title }}

              {% endif %}         

          {% endif %}

     {% endfor %}
              
{% endfor %}
```

So the problem is that the following comparison `{% if video.category_id ==  category.name %}` doesn't work.

I print there's value separately and in print version booth's values are string with same value.

For example 'good' and 'good'.

Has somebody any idea why `{% if video.category_id ==  category.name %}` cannot work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `video.category_id` is a Foreign Key object. When you'll print it, it's going to get the `str` value of that object. Therefore you get 'good'.

`video.category_id ==  category.name` will not work.

I'd suggest writing this

`video.category_id == category`

as your comparison.

So the template code should be.

```
{% for category in categories %}
                    
     <li class="nav-item mt-2">
          <a class="nav-link ml-3 pl-0 pb-3 side-menu-section-name" href="#">
               <img src="{{ category.src }}" width="45px" class="pr-2" alt="Video's Category's Icon">By {{ category.name }}
          </a>
     </li>
     {% for video in videos %}
                        
          {% if video.category_id != None %}
                            
              {% if video.category_id ==  category %}
                    <!-- Here should be posts titles which are in current category -->
                                
                    {{  video.title }}

              {% endif %}         

          {% endif %}

     {% endfor %}
              
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you It was really good answer.

Comment: Just a side comment: you should not name foreign key items with '_id' at the end of the name. There are two problems with it: you get confused: 1) you'll get confused while using it from view or template: it seems like it is holding the id, but actually it is more than that: it is referencing the whole model. 2) in your db the field name it will look like: category_id_id. 2+1) It will look the same when making django queries. So in your example it should not be category_id, but simple category in the Videos model. (one more thing: the model name should not be plural)

Comment: Thank you. Those are good comments which I will take in consideration. I have one more question: How can I get only first 3 posts in second for loop? I tried  ```forloop.counter``` but it doesn't work. ```forloop.counter``` works only if a videos are attached to the category by order.  If for example I take fifth post and attach it to the first category than it's ```forloop.counter``` remains 5 and when I use a code ```{%.if forloop.counter <  3 %} it doesn't fits in to this logic. So I want to find a way to count only posts which were matched and when write a logic. Could you please help me?